# django-multiuploader: failed to find libmagic

Tags: python, django

I installed [django-multiuploader](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiuploader/0.2.4) and follow the instructions. Got error message in browser:

```
ImportError at /competition-big/big1/upload
failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation
```

Here is where error happens:

```
/Users/philip/Documents/python/virtual_env/lauris_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiuploader/forms.py in <module>
import os
import re
import magic ...
from django import forms
...
```

I tired install/uninstall/upgrade `python-magic` and `libmagic` many times(using pip), but error remains. Here is part of my site-package (I am using virtualenv):

[image]


As you can see magic.py is right there. And site-package is on my PYTHONPATH, I double check that. So how can it NOT be found?

I have been fighting for 10+ hours for this. Please help.

Comment: What is the output when you do `pip install -U python-magic`

Comment: are you sure it got installed successfully ? Please post the output on install.

Comment: `Requirement already up-to-date: python-magic in /Users/philip/Documents/python/virtual_env/lauris_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: Positive. Both python-magic and libmagic are successfully installed confirmed by pip. And they're in my virtualenv's site-packages

Comment: how about if you do `import magic` in a shell ? what do you get ?

Comment: @Amyth, I got exact same error in terminal: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/philip/Documents/python/virtual_env/lauris_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/magic.py", line 131, in <module>
    raise ImportError('failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation')
ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!! In magic.py, change this line

```
platform_to_lib = {'darwin': ['/opt/local/lib/libmagic.dylib',
                              '/usr/local/lib/libmagic.dylib',
                              '/usr/local/Cellar/libmagic/5.10/lib/libmagic.dylib'],
```

Change "5.10" to "5.11", because 5.11 is the libmagic version on my Mac.

What a pitfall.. Took me 12 hours to find out